# Random text generator- iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, random, label

I want to make a random text generator, I know how to do a regular one but in this case I cannot get it working. So the code I have take or choose a picture and then it displays it on a different view controller and I want to set the label on that last view controller as a random sentence every time that a picture is taken. I don't know if I explained myself right.. 
This is the code I have:

```
//ViewController.m   

     -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
        if([segue.identifier  isEqualToString:@"CameraSegue"] || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"LibrarySegue"])
        {

            UIImagePickerController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
            controller.sourceType = [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"LibrarySegue"] ?  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary : UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            controller.delegate = self;


        }
        else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowImageViewController"]){

            UIImage *image = (UIImage*)sender;
            ShowImageViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            viewController.pickedImage = image;

            UILabel *label = (UILabel *) sender;
            ShowImageViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
            vc.cap = label;
           //I tried to set the label here
            label.text = @"Hello";

        }
    }

    -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            picker.delegate = nil;
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowImageViewController" sender:image];
        }];
    }

//SeconViewController.h
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *pickedImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *pickedImageView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *cap;

//SecondViewController.m

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.pickedImageView.image = self.pickedImage;
}
```

Comment: I tried just setting the label as a text when the picture is taken with label.text = @"hello"; inside the prepareforsegue method but I got a SIGABRT error.I know I'll have to use the arc4random but I don't know how to use it here.

Comment: Can you please edit your code above to show how you're setting the label's text? My guess is either a) `sender` when it comes through is not a label or, b) you're setting its text with some funky syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with this. It's a c function, but you can use it in objective-c, or convert it.

```
 void generateRandomString() {

      int numRandChars = 15;
      for ( int i = 0; i < numRandChars; i++ ) {

          int intChar = arc4random()%126;

          // Limit to above 33+
          while ( intChar < 33 ) { intChar = arc4random()%126; }

          // Use ascii table to convert
          char aChar = (char)toascii(intChar);

          // Print or do whatever you want with the string
          printf("\n%d = %c",intChar, aChar);
      }
 }
```

Also if you're still having issues setting the label at all, you need to figure out what "sender" actually is, i.e. make sure it's not nil and that it *is* in fact a UILabel as you expect.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, but I don't really know that much C. So I don't really know how to convert it. But I know how to do the random generator, what I don't know is to use it with the prepareforsegue method to generate a label every time I pick a picture

Comment: `arc4random_uniform(u_int32_t upper_bound)` is recommended over `arc4random()%126` constructs. [Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html)

Comment: I think I don't have enough reputation to use it, here is my email: marinemilio@me.com

Answer (score 0):

In swift you can use this to get a consonant and a vowel, just put it on a loop and create your word, hope it helps

```
func getConsonant() {
    var consonant:NSString = "QWRTYPSDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
    var selected = Character(UnicodeScalar(consonant.characterAtIndex(Int(arc4random_uniform(20)))))
    println("This is a consonant \(selected)")
}

func getVowel() {
    var vowel:NSString = "AEIOU"
    var selected = Character(UnicodeScalar(vowel.characterAtIndex(Int(arc4random_uniform(4)))))
    println("This is a vowel \(selected)")
}
```